# How to calculate Sum of a function over a list

Tags: list-manipulation, summation, parametric-functions

`tlist = Table[i, {i, 1, 10}]`

tlist:{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}

`f = E^(-((2 t)/T));`

`Sum[f, {t, {tlist[[i]], {i, 1, 8}}}]`

How to calculate Sum of a function over a list?

One way to do this is by defining `f[t_]:= E^(-((2 t)/T));`
Is there a way to do it in any other manner. Because I have to do this for various functions with a higher level of complexity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Sum[f, {t, tlist}]
```

> ```
>  E^(-20/T) + E^(-18/T) + E^(-16/T) + E^(-14/T) + E^(-12/T) + E^(-10/ T) + 
>   E^(-8/T) + E^(-6/T) + E^(-4/T) + E^(-2/T)
> ```

Comment: lol thanks. Can you please close this question?